# Visual Studio 2013 not using include path

Tags: visual-studio

I have a simple empty Visual Studio 2013 C/C++ project to which added two files:

- MyCode.cpp
- MyCode.h

Inside MyCode.cpp, I have as the first line,

```
#include "mex.h"
```

mex.h is a MATLAB file located in C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v717\extern\include

I have gone to Project Properties -> C/C++ -> General and added "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v717\extern\include" to my "Additional Include Directories".

And yet, VS never finds the file!
File 'mex.h' not found in current source file's directory or in build system paths.

It seems that the build system paths are not being updated with my additional include path.

I've tried using relative paths as well, deleting the .sdf file, and closing/reopening Visual Studio.  It simply won't add the path.

For reference, this works fine in Visual Studio 2010.

Help!

Comment: My crystal ball says that you have the 64-bit version of Windows and use a 32-bit compiler.  So it will get redirected to C:\Program Files (x86).  [Read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Work around this by copying the file(s) to a folder that isn't subject to redirection.  Although there are good odds that whatever you build needs to be a 64-bit program as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I suspected this also, because I noted that VS2013 is in my "Program Files (x86)" folder.  However if I recall, when downloading VS2013 from MSDN, I didn't see a 64-bit version available.  Does such a version exist?

Comment: Also worth noting though, when I placed this file in "C:\Temp" it still couldn't resolve.